# Replace single and double quote in string

Tags: python, string, replace

For a given string, I'm trying to replace single quotes (') and double quotes (") with \' and \" respectively to render it in a Django view.

I'm trying with

```
        lote.descripcion.replace("'", '\'')
        lote.lote.replace("'", "\'")
```

But it doesn't work.

descripcion example:

```
        com_comi'lla22 - fecha: 06/07/2020 - exp: 06/07/2020
```

lote example:

```
        com_comi'lla22
```

Thanks for replies.

Comment: Have you tried: ```lote.descripcion.replace("'",'"')```?

Comment: Try using `r'\''` in place of `'\''` (raw string)

Comment: No, trying ' with \'

Comment: There are two equally valid ways to express a \ in a string constant - either precede the opening quote with `r` (raw string), or double up to \\ inside the constant.  Also remember that when the value is displayed, it will be as `repr(your_string)` and it will _appear_ to have \\ instead of \, but if you just `print` it then it should appear correctly.

Comment: @GeancarloMurillo I don't mean replacing `'\''` with `r'\''` in the **string**. I mean in your **code**. That is, `lote.descripcion.replace("'", r'\'')`  Sorry for any confusion.  (Or maybe less confusingly: `r"\'"` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your exemple to work correctly you have to escape the `\` character also:

```
lote.descripcion.replace("'", '\\\'')
lote.lote.replace("'", "\\'")
```

But you can also check about [MarkupSafe](https://pypi.org/project/MarkupSafe/) which will do it for you. This library is specially done so you can safely insert strings in you html code.

Edit: @RobinZigmond is correct

Comment: Right idea, but instead of `'\\''` shouldn't it be `'\\\''`?

Comment: What is there at present is not syntactically valid. @RobinZigmond is correct. The automatic colourisation should be a bit of a hint here.